# Cron task using root user

Tags: ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I'd like to create a cron task to update a website using Git.

My cron task : `0 0 * * * /var/www/cms/TestMaj/update.sh`

It works manually with these commands :

```
cd /var/www/cms/TestMaj
sudo ./update.sh
```

To create my cron tasks, I've executed this : `sudo crontab -e`

Issue : the cron task is not executed...

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't provide much information that can help us debug this problem. Have you tried replacing your script in cron with something like `echo "my cron job is running" >> /tmp/cron-output.log` and see what's going on? If that works, you can add that to the top of your script and use it to check if it's being called at all or not.

Comment: It works, I put this `* * * * * echo "My cron job is running !" >> /tmp/cron-output.log` and I get this `My cron job is running !` in `/tmp/cron-output.log`...